# Using awk variables outside awk command

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Command

```
awk -F'\t' '{map[$1]=$4}' analytics-details-bkp-ga.txt
```

generates key value map, for example
key1=value1
key2=value2... and so on

I have a for loop that uses this map to obtain value of specific key

```
for i in `cat stores.txt`
 do
     .....
 done
```

I need to use map into above for loop,how to use it.I don't want to write for loop inside awk command.Can someone help on how to use the map generated in awk command outside the awk command?

Comment: what you want to do with the map? can't you do it in awk? it is not easy to export the awk hashtable to shell variable

Comment: In for loop processing is done that generates one file and it has to use the corresponding key value from map to name the file .

Comment: add the requirement in question. it can be done in awk.

Comment: This is an [XY Question](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create associative array (for eg. `map` here ) with something like this :

```
declare -A map
for i in $(awk -F'\t' '{map[$1]=$2} END{ for( key in map) {print key":"map[key] }}' file)
do
   key=${i%:*}
   value=${i#*:}
   map[$key]=$value 
done
```

Comment: Can you explain what does i%:* and i#*: means?

Comment: awk returns the output as key1:value1 key2:value2 ....  etc. For each pair of key:value `i` ,  `${i%:*}` deletes the shortest match of substring in `i` from the back until `:` which gives us the key and the expression   `${i#*:}` deletes the shortest match of substring in `i` from front until `:` which gives us the value.

Comment: Also, from next time please mention all the requirements in the question properly and clearly express what you want to achieve out of it so that it won't appear as XY problem as @Ed-morton said.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible outside awk and it is using the associative array.

Comment: Okay. I second that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `bash >= 4`, then you can make use of associative array,

> If you can post sample input and output, simple `awk` may solve your
>   problem.

**Since you said**

> I need to use map into above for loop,how to use it.I don't want to
>   write for loop inside awk command.

I suggest to use bash associative array,

Sample Input

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat testfile 
foo bar
jack john
me you
now then
so me
```

Script

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A assoc

while read -r col1 col2; do
    assoc["$col1"]=$col2;
done < testfile


for key in "${!assoc[@]}"; do
    echo "${key} ---> ${assoc[${key}]}"
done
```

Output

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ bash test.sh
jack ---> john
so ---> me
now ---> then
foo ---> bar
me ---> you
```

Comment: That's right ++ if you need BASH variables then use BASH otherwise do everything in `awk` itself which is more capable than `bash`

Comment: Yes, thanks for encouraging, unfortunately OP didn't post clearly what he need.